# Views: output item fields grouped by field instead of item?

Tags: views

So currently if I make up a view that outputs three articles with their title and body fields a cleaned up version of the html structure would be:

```
<div class="item-1">
   <div class="title">Item One Title</div>
   <div class="body">Blah Blah Blah......</div>
</div>
   <div class="item-2">
   <div class="title">Item Two Title</div>
<div class="body">Blah Blah Blah......</div>
</div>
<div class="item-3">
   <div class="title">Item Three Title</div>
   <div class="body">Blah Blah Blah......</div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how I can, through Views or the best alternative, make the structure like this instead:

```
<div class="titles">
   <div class="title1">Item One Title</div>
   <div class="title2">Item Two Title</div>
   <div class="title3">Item Three Title</div>
</div>
<div class="bodies">
   <div class="body1">Blah Blah Blah......</div>
   <div class="body2">Blah Blah Blah......</div>
   <div class="body3">Blah Blah Blah......</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Views Attachments. Set up your first View w/ just titles. Then Add display > Attachment, override your Fields to get body and use Attachment settings to position it after the first. Should be a few tutorials out there if this is confusing. Hope it helps.